# how to sort a long list by ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
                print(addition)
                decimal = sum(addition) / len(addition)
                d = decimal * 100
                percentage = float("{0:.2f}".format(d))
                print(percentage)
                list_name_second.append({'Name': x, 'percentage': float(percentage)})
                list_name.append(x)
                addition.clear()

    i = i + 1
if i == num_lines:
    def sort_percentages(list_name_second):
        print(list_name_second.sort('percentage'))

    print(sort_percentages(list_name_second), end='\n\n')
```

the code above is within a loop (apart from the bottom part) it collects percentages and stores then in a list that looks like this:

```
[{'Name': 'Malcolm', 'percentage': '50.0'}]
```

I want to be able to sort the list using the percentages but I don't know how to do this, please help

also the print functions within the calculations were for troubleshooting, dont pay attention to them

Comment: `.sort(key=lambda e: e["percentage"])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's built-in functions `sort()` or `sorted()` where `sort()` method will sort the list in-place, and `sorted()` will return a new sorted list in case you don't need the original list. both `sort()` and `sorted()` have a `key` parameter that specify a callable which will be called on each list's element for comparisons. for more details, see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

if we say that your list for example look like this:

```
>>> list_name_second = [
    {'Name': 'Malcolm', 'percentage': 50.0},
    {'Name': 'Sam', 'percentage': 30.0},
    {'Name': 'Ru', 'percentage': 100.0},
    {'Name': 'Kam', 'percentage': 10.0},
    {'Name': 'Joe', 'percentage': 20.0}
   ]
```

so, you can sort your list `in-place` based on `percentage` key of `dict` list element using `sort(key=callable)` like follows:

```
>>> list_name_second.sort(key=lambda d: d['percentage'])
>>> list_name_second
[{'Name': 'Kam', 'percentage': 10.0}, {'Name': 'Joe', 'percentage': 20.0}, {'Name': 'Sam', 'percentage': 30.0}, {'Name': 'Malcolm', 'percentage': 50.0}, {'Name': 'Ru', 'percentage': 100.0}]
```

or, you can use `sorted(key=callable)` which it will return a new sorted list, like follows:

```
>>> sorted(list_name_second, key=lambda d: d['percentage'])
[{'Name': 'Kam', 'percentage': 10.0}, {'Name': 'Joe', 'percentage': 20.0}, {'Name': 'Sam', 'percentage': 30.0}, {'Name': 'Malcolm', 'percentage': 50.0}, {'Name': 'Ru', 'percentage': 100.0}]
```

here, you are passing a callable lambda function to be applied on each element of the list, which its extract the `'percentage'` key's value from the `dict` and return it to `sort` or `sorted` built-in functions to be used as reference for sorting process.

`Note:` if your elements in the list look like this: `[{'Name': 'Malcolm', 'percentage': '50.0'}]`, where `'percentage'`'s value is a string, you have to cast its value to compared as a float, like this:

```
>>> list_name_second = [
    {'Name': 'Malcolm', 'percentage': '50.0'},
    {'Name': 'Sam', 'percentage': '30.0'},
    {'Name': 'Ru', 'percentage': '100.0'},
    {'Name': 'Kam', 'percentage': '10.0'},
    {'Name': 'Joe', 'percentage': '20.0'}
    ]
>>> sorted(list_name_second, key=lambda d: float(d['percentage']))
[{'Name': 'Kam', 'percentage': '10.0'}, {'Name': 'Joe', 'percentage': '20.0'}, {'Name': 'Sam', 'percentage': '30.0'}, {'Name': 'Malcolm', 'percentage': '50.0'}, {'Name': 'Ru', 'percentage': '100.0'}]
```